# Firebase not initializing before it gets called in other files

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

Im trying to use firebase in a vue project.  I have other js files such as auth.js that use firebase, but im initializing it in my main.js(which should be the entry point for webpack) but it seems like the other files are getting called first? Im using vue-cli with the webpack template.

The error I am getting is

> Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).

Here is the first part of my main.js

```
 // main.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import firebase from 'firebase';
// import firebaseui from 'firebaseui';
import VueFire from 'vuefire';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';
import database from './js/database';

Vue.use(VueFire);

const config = {
  apiKey: '***',
  authDomain: '***',
  databaseURL: '***',
  storageBucket: '***',
  messagingSenderId: '***',
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
database.init();
```

This is my first time really using firebase, any ideas what going on?

Comment: try `import * as firebase from "firebase";`

Comment: @Saurabh Didn't work for me ☹️

Answer (score 4):

This is how i did it

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import { routes } from './routes'
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import { store } from './store/store'

Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueRouter);


const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
});

let config = {
apiKey: "XXXX",
authDomain: "XXXXXX",
databaseURL: "xXxxxxxx",
storageBucket: "XXXXXX",
messagingSenderId: "XXXXXX"
};

Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase.initializeApp(config);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

I did not use vue fire 
But i can use firebase functionality from alll over my app by calling

```
this.$firebase.auth()
this.$firebase.database()
this.$firebase.storage()
```